# RSA asymmentic encryption exception

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I using the following code to generate the public and private key for RSA encryption

```
  public static string RSA_Decrypt(string encryptedText, string privateKey)
        {
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

            rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));

            var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);

            byte[] plainBytes = rsaProvider.Decrypt(buffer, false);

            string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

            return plainText;
        }

        public static string RSA_Encrypt(string data, string publicKey)
        {
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

            rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey));

            byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaProvider.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
        }

        public static Tuple<string, string> CreateKeyPair()
        {
            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 /* PROV_RSA_FULL */ };

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams);

            string publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(false));
            string privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(true));

            return new Tuple<string, string>(privateKey, publicKey);
        }
```

the decrypt function return this exception exception

> "key does not exist"

please advice me to fix this issue.

Comment: Your encryption/decryption methods work correctly when passed the correct keys, double check to be sure you're not passing the public key to the decrypt method.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me (though 384 bits is a very small key size for RSA).

Comment: I posted all function below you can check it.
thank you for your support

Comment: Anything below 1024 bits is certainly not secure, and even 1024 bits is rather weak. People generally recommend 2048 bits.

Comment: thanks for your recommendation I already applied 2048 bit key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code (using the methods you provided) works fine:

```
static void Main()
{
    var keyPair = CreateKeyPair();
    var encryptedText = Encrypt(keyPair.Item2, "test data");
    var decryptedText = Decrypt(keyPair.Item1, encryptedText);
    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted text: {0}", encryptedText);
    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted text: {0}", decryptedText);
}

public static string RSA_Decrypt(string encryptedText, string privateKey)
{
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

    rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey));

    var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);

    byte[] plainBytes = rsaProvider.Decrypt(buffer, false);

    string plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);

    return plainText;
}

public static string RSA_Encrypt(string data, string publicKey)
{
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 };
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

    rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey));

    byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = rsaProvider.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
}

public static Tuple<string, string> CreateKeyPair()
{
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters { ProviderType = 1 /* PROV_RSA_FULL */ };

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, cspParams);

    string publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(false));
    string privateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(true));

    return new Tuple<string, string>(privateKey, publicKey);
}
```

Comment: thanks I get the point,
I used the private key to encrypted and the public for the decrypt

Comment: Only works for small data. i have around 2000 character length string. getting bad length exception

Comment: @KamranShahid - The length of data that can be encrypted by RSA is limited by the size of the key and the padding used. For PKCS#1 padding the maximum message length is the key size (in bytes) - 11 (e.g. a 2048 bit key = 256 bytes, so the maximum message length is 256 - 11 = 245 bytes). For OAEP padding the limit is more complex as it depends also in the size of the hash function used. For large data you can use a hybrid encryption scheme whereby RSA is used only to encrypt a randomly-generated key which is used with a symmetric algorithm (e.g. AES) to encrypt the message itself.

Comment: Tried hybrid implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087158/hybrid-cryptosystem-implementation-in-net-error-specified-key-is-not-a-valid-s but stuck at one point