# RSACryptoServiceProvider (windows) VS RSA (linux)

Tags: c#, linux, rsa

Guys I'm migrating an environment application. It runs on Windows and we will make it available on Linux.

The key saved in the database (private key) was generated with the system running on windows through the method `ExportCspBlob(true)` from class `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

Now I'm trying to retrieve this key to use it on Linux, using the method `ImportRSAPrivateKey` from class `RSA`

```
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection"))
        {
            
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT PRIVATEKEY FROM TABLE", connection);

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            var privateKey = (byte[])reader[0];

            try
            {
                RSA Provider1 = RSA.Create(2048);
                Provider1.ImportRSAPrivateKey(privateKey , out var bytesRead);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                RSACryptoServiceProvider Provider2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048, new CspParameters() { ProviderType = 1 });
                Provider2.ImportCspBlob(privateKey);
            }
        }
```

When doing this procedure always returns the error **"ASN1 corrupted data."** : **"The provided data is tagged with 'Universal' class value '7', but it should have been 'Universal' class value '16'."**

Does anyone know what can it be? How can I maintain compatibility between the data already persisted in the application when it ran on Windows to now that it will run on Linux?

Tks

Comment: A CSP blob is a different format. If you want to import the key with `ImportRSAPrivateKey` then you must export it with `ExportRSAPrivateKey`.

Comment: The problem is that I already have keys persisted in the database. I can't load them with RSA?

Comment: No, you can't. It would be easiest to replace all the CSP blobs in the database with a more interoperable format. A better choice than the "RSA" format that `ExportRSAPrivateKey` uses the PKCS8 format that's used by `ExportPkcs8PrivateKey` or `ExportPkcs8PrivateKeyPem`. Of course it's possible to parse the CSP blob format yourself but it's not trivial and I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **ExportCspBlob** then for import instead of **ImportRSAPrivateKey** you must use [**ImportCspBlob**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.importcspblob?view=net-6.0). Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18872346/7357322)

Comment: ImportCspBlob is only available for RSACryptoServiceProvider, but on Linux RSACryptoServiceProvider is not available, so I can't use it anymore.